# SQL Server strange duplicate key error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In SQL Server 2008 R2, I have a simple table with the following columns definitions:

```
Id (PK ,int , not null)
MeterId (FK , int ,not null)
InstallDate(DateTime, not null)
Image(NVarCharMax, null)
Number (int , not null)
Comments(NVarChar(300), null)
```

And `Id` column is set as `Identity` .

When I run:

```
insert into Transmitters (MeterId, Number, InstallDate)
  values (952, 777 , '2013-02-21')
```

I get the duplicate key error.

There is no other transmitter with id 777 ,

There is a meter with id 952.

This started happening in more than 1 table of my DB.

Any suggestions would be most appriceated.

The entire table script is:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transmitters](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MeterId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [InstallDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Image] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Comments] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Transmitters] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Transmitters]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Transmitter_Meter] FOREIGN KEY([MeterId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Meter] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Transmitters] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Transmitter_Meter]
GO
```

Comment: Is the FK self referencing or do you have a unique constraint on the FK?

Comment: Can you script out the table in its entirety including all constraints?  Also, is the table empty when you insert this record?  Maybe it was already populated and the identity is picking a number that already exists.

Comment: The FK refrences another table: Meters. I do not have any constraints.

Comment: Do you have any other unique index on your table?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear.  When you script out a table, an identity column comes out as [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL.  I want to verify that this is the case.

Comment: Maybe it is a problem with the identity, as some of the values were imported from another table. How can I tell what is the current identity assigned value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , thanks guys you've been most helpful.

I've checked my identity current value using:

```
USE Name_Of_The_DB
GO
DBCC CHECKIDENT (‘Name_Of_The_Table’)
GO
```

It was indeed the cause of the problem that some rows had higher Id values than
the current identity.

Thand I inserted a row to update the current identity value:

```
set identity_insert YourTable ON

--Insert my row

set identity_insert YourTable OFF
```

Thanks :)

Comment: reseeding the identity was actually more appropriate for me: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/database/reset-identity-column-value-in-sql-server/